# When are screenshots appropriate?

Tags: discussion

If anyone is guilty of overusing screenshots it's me.  They are easy to generate, painless to upload and I use them with a vengeance in emails, on web pages, in forum posts and now on StackExchange.

What is the general consensus regarding using screen shots in drupal.SE questions and answers?

Specifically when would it be most appropriate to include a screenshot, and when should they be avoided?

[image: An obvious misuse of the photo upload feature...]

Answer (score 6):

Visual aids are very helpful when describing a problem. If you think a screenshot can illustrate a visual problem you're having, by all means add one. Try to keep most of your question in text. The ultimate goal is to make questions searchable; text is searchable, but images are not.

Screenshots should never be used to show source code.

Answer (score 2):

For answers, I have mixed feelings about screenshots.  They can be beneficial for showing where a buried setting is (like with Panels and Views).  Other times, I think they can be overkill, can be theme dependent, and provide too much "hand-holding" for normal Drupal tasks..